# How to pull a PHP echoed button's text into Javascript, whose value will be used in another PHP Sql query?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP sql query that returns a table.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td id=\"cst\"><button type=\"submit\" id=\"click\" onClick=sendData(this)>".$row["Name"]</button></td></tr>";
```

The table is output correctly. My next step is using vanilla Javascript to pull the HTML text value associated with $row["Name"] from the button in the output table (when the button is clicked). I call the function onClick=sendData(this)

Now, in Javascript I'm attempting to access the text value like so:

```
function sendData(name) {
    var text = name.innerText;
}
```

However, this isn't working. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: a click function exposes the event as a first parameter, try calling it and using it like that to get the text: event.target.innerText

Comment: You might want to close that `<button>` tag

Comment: Why not just have `onClick=sendData(" . $row['name'] . ")`?

Comment: Sorry, the button tag was closed in my actual code. My bad.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I didn't know this was possible. I can give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problem with how you are using both PHP and JavaScript here to solve this problem. 
Let me break them down, and how best we can solve them.

1. **Your ID's are the same :** When you're iterating through the rows in your table, you're not setting a unique id for them. This means if you try to reference them later on in any capacity via JavaScript you won't be able to. Instead, you can change this to something like,  `<td id=\"cst_$row['row_id']\".`
2. **Your PHP is prone to SQL Injection :** The method you're using to query your database is most likely prone to SQL Injection based on how I see you are returning your values. You'd be best to read up on [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
3. **You don't have quotation marks around your onclick :** because you haven't wrapped your function in quotation marks, it actually won't even be sending correctly. However, there is a better solution anyway. Remove the on-click from your button, and add an event listener.
4. **Your button type is of submit :** because you've set your button type to submit, the default behavior is to refresh the page. If you want to keep this, you'd have to specify not to use the default behavior, or simply change the button type, to button.

To solve all of these issues (except SQL Injection because this would require more information than was provided), your code could be changed to the following :

**PHP :**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td id=\"cst_$row['row_id']\"><button class=\"test_buttons\"type=\"button\" id=\"btn_$row['row_id']\"".$row["Name"]</button></td></tr>";
```

In the above example, "row_id" is your unique identifier in your database table. Change this to "id" or whatever you have called it in your table.

**JavaScript :**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("test_buttons"); // Get all buttons you want to search for
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) { // On click of these buttons
      event.preventDefault(); // This is required only if you want to keep the button type of submit
      let text = this.textContent;
      alert(text);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<td><button type="button" class="test_buttons">Test 1</button></td>
<td><button type="button" class="test_buttons">Test 2</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The yet another variant is to improve formatting of your HTML output by taking advantage of [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax that suits well for complex formatting

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo <<<HTML
      <tr>
          <td class="cst"> <!-- class instead `id` -->
              <button
                  type="button" <!-- `button` type instead of `submit` -->
                  class="btn-click" <!-- class instead `id` -->
                  data-name="{$row["Name"]}">
                     {$row["Name"]}
              </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
HTML;
```

And using vanilla JS it is possible to make smth. similar to the result snippet below.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;

  // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
  if (!target.matches('.btn-click')) {
    return;
  }

  var name = target.getAttribute('data-name');
  
  alert('Button `data-name` is "' + name + '"');

  // sendData logic goes further ...
}, false);
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="cst">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-click" data-name="Coockaracha">Reveal my name</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The approach of using global `click` listener is called *event delegation* and has some advantages. You can read about it [here](https://gomakethings.com/listening-for-click-events-with-vanilla-javascript/).

Also keep in mind that **`id` should be unique across the page**, so it is not correct to iterate using `id`. `class` attribute suits nicely and allows multiples.